# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: '.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken .unauthenticated(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication, boot

I am trying to login in spring boot MVC web application. but I am getting the below error.

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.unauthenticated(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)'
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:94) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:359) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1735) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.matoshree")
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityMultiConfig {


    @Order(1)
    @Configuration
    public static class RestConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private MatoshreeUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
        @Autowired
        private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
        //    @Autowired
//    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;
        @Autowired
        private JwtProvider jwtProvider;

        @Bean
        public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12);
            //System.out.println("in WebSecurityConfig passwordEncoder  bCryptPasswordEncoder:"+bCryptPasswordEncoder);
            return bCryptPasswordEncoder;
        }
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("WebSecurityMultiConfig RestConfiguration configure");

            http
                    .antMatcher("/matoshree/**")
                    .cors()
                    .and()

                      .csrf().disable()
                    // dont authenticate this particular request
                    .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/matoshree/rest/loginUserWithJWT",
                    "/matoshree/rest/GetTransKey","matoshree/rest/registeruser","matoshree/rest/updateFCMToken",
                    "matoshree/rest/validateOtp","matoshree/rest/generateOtp","matoshree/rest/loginuser").permitAll().


                    // all other requests need to be authenticated
                            anyRequest().authenticated()
                     .and()
//                    .addFilter(new JwtTokenFilter(userDetailsService,jwtProvider))
//                    .addFilter(new JwtTokenFilter(userDetailsService,jwtProvider))
                    //.anyRequest().authenticated().and().
                    // make sure we use stateless session; session won't be used to
                    // store user's state.
                           .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
//            .csrf()
//                    .disable() // we don't need CSRF because our token is invulnerable
//                    .authorizeRequests()
//                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
//                    .antMatchers(RESET_PASSWORD_URL).permitAll()
//                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
//                    .and()
//                    .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
//                    .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
//                    // this disables session creation on Spring Security
//                    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
            // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
            http.addFilterBefore(new JwtTokenFilter(userDetailsService,jwtProvider), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authBuilder) throws Exception {
            // authBuilder.authenticationProvider(CustomAuthenticationProvider );
            authBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        }
        @Bean
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception{
            System.out.println("in c authenticationManagerBean  ");
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }

        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            // configure AuthenticationManager so that it knows from where to load
            // user for matching credentials
            // Use BCryptPasswordEncoder
            auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        }

    }

//    @Order(2)
//    @Configuration
//    public static class AskRestConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
//        @Autowired
//        AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;
//
//        @Override
//        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
////            http
////                    .antMatcher(ASKFAST_API + "/**")
////                    .csrf().disable()
////                    .authorizeRequests()
////                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
////                    .and()
////                    .httpBasic()
////                    .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
////                    .and()
////                    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS) //We don't need sessions to be created.
////            ;
//        }
//    }

    @Order(2)
    @Configuration
    public static class WebConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private MatoshreeUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
        @Autowired
        private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;


        @Bean
        public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12);
            //System.out.println("in WebSecurityConfig passwordEncoder  bCryptPasswordEncoder:"+bCryptPasswordEncoder);
            return bCryptPasswordEncoder;
        }
//        @Bean
//        public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
//            http
//                    //.authorizeHttpRequests()
//                    .authorizeRequests()
//                    .antMatchers("/", "/home","/login","/goToLogin").permitAll()
//                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
//                    .and()
//                    .formLogin()
//                    .loginPage("/goToLogin")
//                    .permitAll()
//                    .and()
//                    .logout()
//                    .permitAll();
//
//            return http.build();
//        }
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            System.out.println("WebSecurityMultiConfig WebConfiguration configure");
            http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
//            http
//                    //.authorizeHttpRequests()
//                    .authorizeRequests()
//                    //.antMatchers("/", "/home","/login","/goToLogin").permitAll()
//                    .anyRequest().authenticated();

//                    http
//                    .csrf().disable()
//                    .antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests()
//                    .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
//                    //.antMatchers("/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
//                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
//                    .and().formLogin();
//
//            http.sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1).expiredUrl("/goToLogin");
//                    .and()
//                    .formLogin()
//                    .loginPage("/goToLogin")
//                    .permitAll()
//                    .and()
//                    .logout()
//                    .permitAll();

//                   http
//                    .antMatcher("/**")
//                    // .csrf().disable()
//                     // .authorizeRequests()
//                    //.and()
////                    .authorizeRequests()
////                     .antMatchers("/**/favicon.ico", "/**/*.css", "/**/*.js","/**/*.jpg", "/**/*.png", "/**/*.xlsx", "/fonts/**", "/logout").permitAll()
////                    .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources/**", "/configuration/security", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**").permitAll()
//                //.antMatchers( "/goToLogin","/home","/login","/goToRegistration","/registeruser","/search").permitAll()
//                //.anyRequest().authenticated()
//               // .and()
//                .formLogin()
//                .loginPage("/goToLogin")
//                .permitAll()
//                .and()
//                .logout()
//                .permitAll();

                   //////
                  http
                    .antMatcher("/**")
                   // .csrf()
                    //.and()
               .csrf().disable()
                    .authorizeRequests()
//                    .antMatchers("/**/favicon.ico", "/**/*.css", "/**/*.js", "/**/*.png", "/**/*.xlsx", "/fonts/**", "/logout").permitAll()
//                    .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources/**", "/configuration/security", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/goToLogin","/home","/login","/goToRegistration","/registeruser","/403"/*,"/goToSearch"*/).permitAll()
                     .antMatchers("/search","/goToSearch").hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_SSR","ROLE_CSR","ADMIN", "SSR","CSR")
                    //.antMatchers(RESET_PASSWORD_PAGE_URL, PRIVACY_POLICY).permitAll()
                    //.anyRequest().hasAnyRole("ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_SSR","ROLE_CSR")
                     .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .formLogin()
                     .permitAll()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                     .usernameParameter("emailId")
                      .passwordParameter("password")
                       .loginProcessingUrl("/doLogin")
//                      .defaultSuccessUrl("/login_success")
//                      .failureUrl("/login_error")
//                       .successForwardUrl("/login_success_handler")
//                        .failureForwardUrl("/login_failure_handler")
                    //.permitAll()
                    //.defaultSuccessUrl(EMPLOYEE_MVC, true)
                    .and()
                    .logout()
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout");
            http
                    .sessionManagement()
                    .maximumSessions(1).sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());
        }

        @Bean
        public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
            return new SessionRegistryImpl();
        }
        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web
                    .ignoring()
                    .antMatchers(
                            HttpMethod.GET,
                            "/",
                            "/*.html",
                            "/**/favicon.ico",
                            "/**/*.html",
                            "/**/*.css",
                            "/**/*.js",
                            "/**/*.xlsx",
                            "/**/*.png",
                            "/**/*.jpg"
                    ) ;
        }

        @Bean
        public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
            System.out.println("WebSecurityMultiConfig WebConfiguration authenticationProvider userDetailsService:"+userDetailsService);
            DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
            authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
            authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

            return authProvider;
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("WebSecurityMultiConfig WebConfiguration configure auth:"+auth);
            auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
        }
//        @Autowired
//        public void configureInMemoryAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
//        {
//           // auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("ankush.shejal04@gmail.com").password(passwordEncoder().encode("Ankush@123")).roles("CSR");
//            auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
//        }
//        @Override
//        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authBuilder) throws Exception {
//            // authBuilder.authenticationProvider(CustomAuthenticationProvider );
//            authBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
////            authBuilder.inMemoryAuthentication()
////                    .withUser("ankush.shejal04@gmail.com")
////                    .password(passwordEncoder().encode("Ankush@123"))
////                    .authorities("ROLE_CSR");
//        }

        @Bean
        public   AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception{
            System.out.println("in c authenticationManagerBean  ");
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }
//
//        @Autowired
//        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
//            // configure AuthenticationManager so that it knows from where to load
//            // user for matching credentials
//            // Use BCryptPasswordEncoder
//            auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
////            auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
////                    .withUser("ankush.shejal04@gmail.com")
////                    .password(passwordEncoder().encode("Ankush@123"))
////                    .authorities("ROLE_CSR");
//        }
    }


}
```

Comment: These errors come from using incompatible versions. You are probably mixing jars from different versions of Spring Security.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable response . it helped me a lot . i have been fixing this issue from last week.